Azure load balancer map to active pod
I have an azure load balancer service that sends requests to the active pod in a pair of pods:

pod0 is labeled active as part of the startup process
pod1 is labeled not active, so pod0 is active and pod1 is backup.

When pod0 goes down the azure lb keeps sending requests to pod0 even though the 2 pods know that pod1 is now active.
I'm not sure how the azure lb is supposed to get updated to point to pod1 as now being the active pod, as both pods can see who is active and who is backup. Suggestions, ideas please?
K8s configuration changes not helping in this case such as changing app name and selectors to match
